# Is there a way to get codeclimate to run on files without extensions?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, code-climate

I am looking a getting [codeclimate](https://docs.codeclimate.com/) utilised more widely in our repository ([pycbc](https://github.com/gwastro/pycbc))

This is organised with modules named e.g. `module.py` in one folder and executables in the bin folder with names like `pycbc_do_something` (note no extension).

We use codeclimate to check code quality on each MR, set up as described in the documentation, but the executables do not get checked

I have tried using negated `exclude-patterns` to specifically whitelist the executables

However there is a rule on extensions separate to this, where codeclimate decides which engine to use based on the file extension:

> Furthermore, engines only run their analysis on files with an appropriate file extension for the language being analyzed (.rb for a Ruby engine, .py for a Python engine, etc). Therefore, in most cases you should not need to specify excludes for files in languages other than your target languages.

https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/excluding-files-and-folders#auto-generated-file-and-folder-exclusions

So if a file has no extension, it seems that nothing is done. Is that correct?

I can't see anything within the docs where we can specify the language in this case. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could you use the `fetch` section of the config to fetch your extension free file and  save it with an extension?